# Is that official android market api is available? Need to get market application version, Features etc

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

```
Does Google expose their Google play API?. How to get the Application 
version, Features & Additional information.
```

**I need to Show the customized alert(contains text of new features available in latest app version) to user, When user using old version.**

Answer (score 1):

There is no official market api. You can use third party ones, such as this [open source one](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).